# Not compact embeddings of Sobolev spaces in $L^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

We know that if $1\leq p < \infty$, the following embbedings of Sobolev spaces in $\mathbb{R}^k$ are true:

- $\text { if } 1 \leq p<k, W^{1, p}\left(\mathbb{R}^{k}\right) \subset L^{q}\left(\mathbb{R}^{k}\right) \text { with } q \in\left[p, p_{*}\right] \text { and } p_{*}=\frac{kp}{k-p}$
- $W^{1, k}\left(\mathbb{R}^{k}\right) \subset L^{q}\left(\mathbb{R}^{k}\right) \text { for every } q \in[k, \infty)$
- $\text { if } p>N, W^{1, p}\left(\mathbb{R}^{k}\right) \subset L^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^{k}\right)$.

Now, I am interested in proving that these emmbedings are not compacts. I am a little lost with this proof, I have found this related quiestion [$W^{1,1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is not compactly embedded in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1557307/w1-1-mathbbrn-is-not-compactly-embedded-in-l1-mathbbrn), but I don't know if the proof which appears there can be generalised to answer my question.

Comment: Essentially, You can always take a fixed very nice function $f$ and consider the sequence $f(x-(k,0,\dots,0))$ for $k \in N$. Then show that this sequence is bounded in $W^{k,p}$, nur has no convergent subsequence in $L^q$.

Comment: Is the argument to prove that it has not convergent subsequences similar to which is used in the linked question?